# How remove and prevent creating posts with duplicate post_names

Tags: wordpress

frist thank you for big county

secound

im have problem in same posts it show 2 posts with same name with 2 different content and id for posts

im try disable all plugin and change theme with "Twenty Nineteen"

and nothing change after refrech

also i check theme

i using this sql to find 2 posts i see it at one post

```
SELECT id, post_title, post_status, post_type, SUBSTR(post_content, LOCATE('Carob is an evergreen flowering tree whose', post_content) -1, 100) FROM wpw8_posts WHERE locate('Carob is an evergreen flowering tree whose', post_content) > 0
```

[image]

[image]

how to check this problem i try debug but nothing show as error or problem in page

i can attach content-single.php and single.php but i already set to default theme of wordpres so i dont where i can find this problem

"post make with autopost plugin"

Comment: Hi @ẪĦmẻḓ MøĦẫmẻḓ. Could you please clarify your question? Are you saying that if you execute your SELECT statement, you should see two posts in the results? And, the problem is that you only see one post? And you would like to know how to debug this problem?

Comment: @kofeigen yes i try edit post from wp admin only see frist post other not what i can do to remove other post or make every post in different post

Comment: Do you know the **ID** of both posts? You say the posts **have the same name**. It sounds like you know how to find both posts in the database, but you do not see these posts on the Admin page or on the front-end. Is this true? On the Admin page that lists the posts (**/wp-admin/edit.php**), did you look to see if the missing post is in the Trash? If you see both posts in the database, what are the values of the **post_status** field?

Comment: @kofeigen it show in front end 2 posts in 1 post url and in phpmyadmin publish , why try edit it show only one post other post id 180107 and frist post id 378242 , you can see here the 2 posts i see other posts like that but only few posts like 5 or 10 , https://shorturl.at/fuyDI

Comment: Thank you for the link. I see two posts. The one with ID=180107 was created on 2023-02-02T17:20:40 (GMT). The other one with ID=378242 was created on 2023-04-07T03:22:29 (GMT). The post_content is not the same for both. Sorry, but I do not understand the problem. Do you want to stop making posts that use a post_title already in use (to stop making duplicate slugs)? Are you using a WordPress plugin that is automatically creating these posts for you? Your question says, "**post make with autopost plugin**". Is the problem with the plugin? What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: thank you, yes i don't want 2 posts like this just like normal new slug for sec post like at end URL 2, plugin name (wordpress automatic)

Comment: Use a [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook in a plugin or child theme. **save_post** executes immediately **after** a post has been saved. Inside your hook callback function, you can check to see if the new post is using the same **post_title** as an existing post. If it is the same, you can decide what to do: e.g. 1. delete the new post; 2. give the new post_title a unique name; 3. log the event for future review by an administrator, etc. Are you able to write code for a custom plugin or child theme?

Comment: i dont know good about wordpress developer only few , i can easy delete sec post but i want stop the problem for ever or even get all posts list have 2 post to clean it , i dont know how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to check and delete a duplicate post slug (post_name) can look like the sample below. It uses the WordPress action hook [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/).

## WARNING: Test all code on a development/test site before testing on your live/production site!

This code has not been tested. By default WordPress avoids duplicate **post_name**s by automatically changing the `post_name` before the post is saved to the database. In your case, your plugin might be doing something to avoid the default behavior. Please test this on a test site before deploying it to a live site. And, before deployment please remember to back up your database.

### Delete duplicate posts

```
function delete_post_with_duplicate_post_name( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $force_delete = false;

    // Do not touch updates to existing posts.
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    $posts = \get_posts( array(
        'post_name__in' => array( $post->post_name ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 2
    ) );

    if ( 2 === count( $posts ) ) {
        \wp_delete_post( $post_id, $force_delete );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'delete_post_with_duplicate_post_name', 10, 3 );
```

The `$force_delete` option controls if the post is sent to the **Trash** or **permanently deleted** immediately. If sent to the trash you have an opportunity to see who the author is, determine if the post should replace the original, and recover it if needed.

### Search for duplicate posts

A SQL query to search for duplicate posts could look like this:

```
use DATABASE_NAME;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, P.post_name
FROM wp_posts P
WHERE P.post_name <> ''
  AND P.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY P.post_name
HAVING Count > 1;
```

After you find the duplicate posts, you can do another query to search for the post **ID** and delete the posts in Admin.

## Update #2: Delete all duplicate posts

### The code below has not been tested

The code should delete all duplicate posts based on `post_name` and `post_status`. You can add it to the main file of your plugin or child theme, use it to remove duplicate posts, then remove it once the duplicate posts have been removed.

The statement that deletes the post has been commented out for testing. First, confirm that the code is finding the correct posts before removing the comment from that statement.

The code must execute from within WordPress and not directly on the database because the `wp_delete_post` function deletes meta data and other entities associated with the post. Read the WP Documentation on [wp_delete_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/)

```
function dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts() {
    global $wpdb;
    $force_delete = false;

    $order = 'ASC';

    $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

    // Find duplicate slugs.
    $sql  = "";
    $sql .= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, P.post_name";
    $sql .= " FROM {$table_prefix}posts P";
    $sql .= " WHERE P.post_name <> ''";
    $sql .= " AND P.post_status = 'publish'";
    $sql .= " GROUP BY P.post_name";
    $sql .= " HAVING Count > 1";
    $sql .= ";";

    $post_names = $wpdb->get_col( $sql, 1 );

    if ( count( $post_names ) > 0 ) {

        // Find IDs of duplicates.
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT P.ID, P.post_name, P.post_date";
        $query .= " FROM {$table_prefix}posts P";
        $query .= ' WHERE P.post_name IN (' . implode(', ', array_fill(0, count( $post_names ), '%s') ) . ')';
        $query .= " AND P.post_status = 'publish'";
        $query .= " ORDER BY P.post_name, P.post_date {$order}";
        $query .= ";";

        $sql2 = call_user_func_array(
            array( $wpdb, 'prepare' ),
            array_merge(
                array( $query ),
                $post_names
            )
        );

        $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $sql2, 'ARRAY_A' );
        $previous_posts = array();
        $found_posts = array();

        // Delete all except the earliest posts for each set of duplicate posts.
        foreach ( $posts as $index => $current ) {
            if ( $index > 0 && $current['post_name'] !== $previous_posts[0]['post_name'] ) {
                foreach ( $previous_posts as $index2 => $previous_post ) {
                    if ( $index2 > 0 ) { // Avoid deleting the first post.
                        /**
                         * Remove the comment from this line when you have
                         * confirmed the correct posts are found.
                         */
                        // \wp_delete_post( $previous_post['ID'], $force_delete );

                        /**
                         * For testing.
                         * Comment out the line below when you have
                         * confirmed the correct posts are found.
                         */
                        $found_posts[] = $previous_post;
                    }
                }
                $previous_posts = array();
            }
            $previous_posts[] = $current;
        }
        foreach ( $previous_posts as $index3 => $previous_post ) {
            if ( $index3 > 0 ) {
                \wp_delete_post( $previous_post['ID'], $force_delete );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * For testing.
     * Comment out the line below when you have
     * confirmed the correct posts are found.
     * Instead of echo you could save the result
     * from print_r() to a file and use the file
     * as a reference when verifying the posts in
     * the database or in the WP Admin pages.
     */
    echo print_r( $found_posts, true );
}

add_action( 'init', 'dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts', 10, 1 );
```

## UPDATE #3 Preventing duplicate posts

Since the "autopost" plugin does not use the REST API you have at least the four options listed below--three of them **do not need** cron.

### 1. delete_post_with_duplicate_post_name (cron not needed)

Add the **delete_post_with_duplicate_post_name** function to your own plugin or child theme. And include `add_action( 'save_post', 'delete_post_with_duplicate_post_name', 10, 3 );`.

### 2. dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts (cron not needed)

Add the **dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts** function to your own plugin or child theme. And include `add_action( 'init', 'dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts', 10, 1 );`.

### 3. cron

If you do not want options **1.** or **2.** to execute on every server request, you can use cron to execute the code less frequently based on a schedule that you design. Some servers provide a cron interface to make it easy to configure. Some servers do not make it easy, and you have to write the command line code yourself. The basic idea with cron is to configure a regular schedule to execute a PHP script on the server. This is not easy to explain because it might require using [WordPress CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/query/) or writing PHP scripts that use database credentials to access the database directly. I think it is easier for you to avoid cron.

### 4. WordPress cron task (cron not needed)

[WordPress Cron Scheduling](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/) is your best option in my opinion. It is almost like the [standard cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) but does not require writing and adding a special PHP script to the server. You can follow the steps outlined below. To learn more you can look at the examples in the WordPress Documentation for [Cron Scheduling](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/).

The main difference between WordPress cron and the standard cron is this:
The standard cron can be scheduled to execute a script at exact, regular time intervals using precise time-of-day settings.
WordPress cron time intervals and execution times are not exact. The script or function is executed at the moment a page is requested if that moment occurs after the interval has passed. Precise time intervals are not important for cleaning up duplicate posts. So, WordPress cron is fine for this purpose.

#### Step #1: Add dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts

Add the **dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts** function to your own plugin or child theme. And **do not** include the statement `add_action( 'save_post', 'dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts', 10, 3 );`.

##### Step #1.1: Update SQL queries

Since you know that the "autopost" plugin creates duplicate posts in **draft** mode, both SQL queries in **dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts** should be updated to find posts with a status of *publish* **OR** *draft*.

###### Edit $sql query

The **$sql** query needs to have this line:

```
$sql .= " AND P.post_status = 'publish'";
```

...changed to...

```
$sql .= " AND ( P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'draft' )";
```

###### Edit $query query

And these lines from the **$query** query need to be changed from:

```
$query .= " AND P.post_status = 'publish'";
$query .= " ORDER BY P.post_name, P.post_date {$order}";
```

...to...

```
$query .= " AND ( P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'draft' )";
$query .= " ORDER BY P.post_name ASC, P.post_status DESC, P.post_date {$order} ASC";
```

These changes sort the search results first by *post_name*, then by *post_status*, then by *post_date* so that *publish* posts are listed before *draft* posts. This sorting order assumes that the post you want to keep was published before the posts you want deleted.

#### Step #2: Schedule WP Cron

Add the code below to the same plugin or child theme from **Step #1**. This will call the **dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts** function once every hour. This could be much less frequent than calling the function on every page request, and will help avoid slower web site performance.

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_duplicate_posts_preventer' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_duplicate_posts_preventer' );
}

add_action( 'my_duplicate_posts_preventer', 'dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts' );
```

#### Step #3 (optional)

It probably does not apply to your case, but if you ever need to unschedule the WordPress cron task you can follow the instructions from the [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/#unscheduling-tasks).

## UPDATE #4 Preventing duplicate posts before post creation

WordPress documentation for **wp_insert_post** lists associated [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#hooks). The hook [wp_insert_post_empty_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_empty_content/) fires before the post is saved, which is perfect for preventing duplicate posts from being created. The hook passes unsaved post information to the hook callback function which can be used to test for duplicates.

The purpose of the hook is to test for an empty *title*, *excerpt* and *author*. The developer can write their own test conditions in the hook callback and return *true* (the Post is empty and **will not** be saved) or *false* (the Post is not empty and **will** be saved). When *true* is returned, the hook produces these error messages: *Publishing failed. Content, title, and excerpt are empty.* or *Updating failed. Content, title, and excerpt are empty.*.

The code below demonstrates how this hook can be used to prevent duplicate posts.

### prevent_duplicate_post()

#### Auto Draft posts

When the *Add New Post* option is selected, WordPress automatically creates a placeholder post with a post_status of **auto-draft**. If the *wp_insert_post_empty_content* callback function (the function **prevent_duplicate_post** below) returns *true*, the **auto-draft** post is not automatically deleted. To remove these auto-draft posts you could either call [wp_delete_auto_drafts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_auto_drafts/) within the callback function, or use a WordPress Cron-scheduled function. **wp_delete_auto_drafts()** deletes auto-draft posts older than 7 days. With a WordPress Cron-scheduled function you can use a regular schedule and custom delay (e.g. delete auto-draft posts older than 3 days).

```
/**
 * Callback function for 'wp_insert_post_empty_content' filter hook.
 *
 * @param $maybe_empty bool  Whether the post should be considered "empty".
 * @param $post_info   array Associative array of Post data.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function prevent_duplicate_post( bool $maybe_empty, array $post_info ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $title = $post_info['post_title'];
    $post_id = $post_info['ID'];

    // Find duplicate post titles.
    $sql  = "";
    $sql .= "SELECT P.post_title";
    $sql .= " FROM {$table_prefix}posts P";
    $sql .= " WHERE P.post_title = %s";
    $sql .= " AND ( P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'draft' )";
    $sql .= " AND ( P.ID <> %d )";
    $sql .= ";";

    $sql2 = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $title, $post_id );
    $wpdb->query( $sql2 );

    if ( $wpdb->num_rows > 0 ) {
        wp_delete_auto_drafts();
        return true; // Duplicate found. Reject post creation.
    } else {
        return false; // No duplicate found. Create the post.
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'prevent_duplicate_post', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you , but that mean need edit all post not delete it automatic without edit in wp admin , how to do script remove all then use the code to stop any duplicate posts , after search in database " Showing rows 0 - 499 (5485 total, Query took 0.0077 seconds.)" that to large

Comment: The query is probably finding revisions and counting more posts than it should. I updated the query in my answer to avoid revisions. Please try the updated query to see how many duplicates you find. If you still see too many posts and want to delete posts automatically, you need to decide which ones should be deleted. The first version? The second? The latest? Do you know which ones you want to keep?

Comment: thank you i only want frist post stay and other delete , then how to delete it with sql

Comment: Hi @ẪĦmẻḓ MøĦẫmẻḓ I just added the code for deleting duplicate posts. You **MUST** test the code to confirm it is finding the correct posts before using it on your production server. There are no guarantees the code works. If you find problems, please provide details, and I will try to help. Thanks.

Comment: thank you,i will test it and contact with plugin developer to check it

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know if it works or if there are problems.

Comment: Hi @ẪĦmẻḓ MøĦẫmẻḓ. I just noticed that when I copied the code to find duplicate posts in the `dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts()` the `COUNT(*)` function was missing in the SELECT statement. My answer was updated with the correction. Please try this updated version and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @ẪĦmẻḓ MøĦẫmẻḓ. Please remember to copy the whole `dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts()` updated function. Other changes were made in addition to changes in the SELECT statatement.

Comment: thank it move all posts duplicated to trash only left frist post of all posts duplicated , mysql after delete posts from trash retrun 0 that good now how to stop this posts , i was contact with developer and he said that for cron job same time duplicated posts if run cron from plugin settings , how can sure that posts dont duplicated again?

Comment: Hi @ẪĦmẻḓ MøĦẫmẻḓ. Do you know how the plugin works? Can you ask the plugin author if the plugin creates posts using server-side functions (e.g. [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)), or client-side functions (e.g. using the [WordPress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/))? If REST API is used, we might be able to stop the creation of duplicate posts before they are created. If server-side functions are used, we might only be able to delete the duplicate after it is created.

Comment: thank you i try heis way to use cpanel cron job for make sure this not happen again , https://valvepress.com/wordpress-internal-cron-job-work-may-need-setup-external-cron/ , i hope this not happen again or you have idea to stop any posts with same name from publish and delete it after create draft post or publish post

Comment: yes standard no post type used

Comment: it create post as draft with normal not with rest api, about dangerously_delete_duplicate_posts never know about before can you explain more how use with cron job

Comment: thank you you answer help me to clean posts thank god and thank you for help but if it happen again how stop it

Comment: it really help but now can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139674/remove-all-id-class-style-from-wordpress-posts-with-sql

Comment: can you add code to just stop any duplicated posts not delete it with full code like your answer , im delete from database all duplicated posts now only i need code for stop any new duplicated posts

Comment: thank you i will test least code you add,where i can mark question accept? only show is follow and share answer nothing else

Comment: thank you i hope you have good life and god send to you helps always 

Comment: test it and it stop create post, i think that well help but dont know if help when plugin duplicated post

Comment: after test code server admin tell me site got big load , this is report
SELECT   wpw8_posts.*
   FROM wpw8_posts 
   WHERE 1=1  AND (((wpw8_posts.post_title LIKE '%Surat%') OR (wpw8_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%Surat%') OR (wpw8_posts.post_content LIKE '%Surat%')) AND ((wpw8_posts.post_title LIKE '%Al-Nasr%') OR (wpw8_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%Al-Nasr%') OR (wpw8_posts.post_content LIKE '%Al-Nasr%')))  AND wpw8_posts.post_type

Comment: IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND ((wpw8_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpw8_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wpw8_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wpw8_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wpw8_posts.post_status = 'trash' OR wpw8_posts.post_status = 'auto-draft' OR wpw8_posts.post_status = 'private'))