# remove all id,class,style from wordpress posts with sql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I try to find a way to clean up old posts from the wordpress database with a sql command

```sql
UPDATE `wpw8_posts` SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<span id=".*?" class=".*?" style=".*?">.*?</span>', '<span>.*?</span>');
```

```
UPDATE `wpw8_posts` SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<h2 id=".*?" class=".*?" style=".*?">.*?</h2>', '<h2>.*?</h2>');
```

```
UPDATE `wpw8_posts` SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<p id=".*?" class=".*?" style=".*?">.*?</p>', '<p>.*?</p>');
```

What I need is to search and remove any random style or id or class to make sure the code is cleaned up.

Existing:

```html
<span id="geruhgk" class="fkhdge" style="gjfjgr">content</span>
<p class="fkhdge" style="gjfjgr" id="geruhgk">content</p>
<h2 class="fkhdge" id="geruhgk" style="gjfjgr">content</h2>
```

Expected:

```html
<span>content</span>
<p>content</p>
<h2>content</h2>
```

I tried the following sql command:

```sql
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'<div class="(?s)(.*?)">(?s)(.*?)</div>','<div>(?s)(.*?)</div>')
```

That didn't work. I dont know how to write the REGEXP. What I need to edit to search for like random classes or id or style and how to search and remove old id,class,style for all posts in the wordpress database.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is a bit tricky and I don't know about a good solution for your problem. I would suggest writing a PHP script and use a HTML parser library instead. You could use `$wpdb` or the wordpress internal functions `get_post/s` and `update_post` to get and update the posts content.

Comment: from php it can break sute with posts then 75k so its better with mysql,can same one help with that

Comment: Hi @ẪĦmẻḓMøĦẫmẻḓ Please see my comment [here](https://todo.sr.ht/~kofeigen/deduplication/2) and let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: 404 Not Found *_* please readd sql command

Comment: UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE( `post_content`, '/<span(.?)((id=[^ ]+|class=[^ ]+|style=[^ ]+)\s)+(.?)\>(.?)<\/span\>/', '<span$1$4>$5</span>'); it need login to show code , test and tell you

Comment: i try this (UPDATE `wpw8_posts`
SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE( `post_content`, '/<oo(.?)((id=[^ ]+|class=[^ ]+|style=[^ ]+)\s)+(.?)\>(.?)<\/oo\>/', '<oo$1$4>$5</oo>');)
nothing change with im have post <oo id="gduhu uhcuhc gciuhiu" class="hdfkjhgk hdfkjghk" style="color:red"></oo> to test it <  0 rows affected. (Query took 3.0054 seconds.)

Comment: please same help with this code dont work UPDATE `wpw8_posts` SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE( `post_content`, '<oo(.?)((id=[^ ]+|class=[^ ]+|style=[^ ]+)\s)+(.?)\>(.?)<\/oo\>', '<oo$1$4>$5</oo>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB uses the backslash character (`\`), not the dollar sign (`$`) as the regular expression back-reference character. I am guessing that the web host you are using with phpMyAdmin is using a MariaDB database. If this is true you can try this:

```
UPDATE `wpw8_posts`
SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<(span|p|h2) ((id|class|style)="[^>]+")+', '<\\1');
```

You can add many HTML tag names to the list of **span**, **p**, and **h2** to update multiple tags.

Comment: thank you i need more test cuz html code alot so i dont know if samething got worng if i use it for 70k posts

Comment: i dont test UPDATE `wpw8_posts`
SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<(span|p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|strong|i|em|dd|dt|code|small|video|col|colgroup|pre|hr|br|ul|li|ol|table|tbody|tr|td|th|thead|tfoot|iframe|img|a) ((id|class|style|dir|data-aa-component|alt|width|height|title)="[^>]+")+', '<\\1'); but need more time for more tests

Comment: final code for who have same problem UPDATE `wpw8_posts`
SET `post_content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`post_content`, '<(span|p|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|strong|i|em|dd|dt|code|small|video|col|colgroup|pre|hr|br|ul|li|ol|table|tbody|tr|td|th|thead|tfoot|iframe|img|a) ((id|class|style|dir|data-aa-component|alt|width|height|title|rowspan|colspan|data-row|itemprop|itemscope|itemtype)="[^>]+")+', '<\\1'); thank you @kofeigen